# Problem when try to extract day from created_at Laravel with PostgreSQL

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I have a question and a problem, I think, with a little more difficulty and I would like a somewhat useful solution.Let's say I have data for 30 days
And an array with 30 elements each element meaning day 1, 2, 3 etc
I would like to calculate for each day how many dates there are on that day
For example, I have

```
created_at
 created_at: "2022-05-30 23:01:00",
 created_at: "2022-05-1 23:01:00",
 created_at: "2022-05-2 23:01:00",
 created_at: "2022-05-3 23:01:00",
 created_at: "2022-05-3 23:01:00",
 created_at: "2022-05-3 23:01:00",
 created_at: "2022-05-3 23:01:00",
```

In that array I will have

```
[30 => 1, 1 => 1, 2 => 1, 3 => 4]
```

Each position will mean the day and the number of dates for that day
For now, I'm just taking the data from a range
My query is

```
$orders = Order::selectRaw('count(*) as count, EXTRACT(DAY FROM TIMESTAMP created_at) as date')
            ->groupByRaw('DATE(created_at)')
            ->where('created_at', '>=', $interval)
            ->pluck('count', 'date');

        dd($orders);
```

But I get the following error

```
Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "created_at"
LINE 1: ...ect count(*) as count, EXTRACT(DAY FROM TIMESTAMP created_at...
```

Did I write something wrong in this query?